# Wave Analytics results binding

Tags: einstein-analytics

I am trying to bind the results of one dashboard steps to be used in another dashboard step. Assume that I have the following "source" step:

```
"Source_Step": {
                "datasets": [
                    {
                        "id": "0Fxx0000000HDKJFL",
                        "label": "Opportunity Lines Items",
                        "name": "Opportunity_Line_Items",
                        "url": "/services/data/v40.0/wave/datasets/0Fxx0000000HDKJFL"
                    }
                ],
                "isFacet": true,
                "isGlobal": false,
                "label": "Compare Table by Record Type & Quarter",
                "query": {
                    "measures": [
                        [
                            "sum",
                            "TotalPrice",
                            "A"
                        ]
                    ],
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "query": {
                                "measures": [
                                    [
                                        "sum",
                                        "TotalPrice"
                                    ]
                                ],
                                "groups": [
                                    "OpportunityId.RecordTypeId.Name",
                                    [
                                        "OpportunityId_CloseDate_Year",
                                        "OpportunityId_CloseDate_Quarter"
                                    ]
                                ],
                                "filters": [
                                    [
                                        "OpportunityId_ForecastCategory",
                                        [
                                            "Closed",
                                            "Forecast"
                                        ],
                                        "in"
                                    ]
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "groups": [
                        "OpportunityId.RecordTypeId.Name",
                        [
                            "OpportunityId_CloseDate_Year",
                            "OpportunityId_CloseDate_Quarter"
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                "selectMode": "single",
                "type": "aggregateflex",
                "useGlobal": true,
                "visualizationParameters": {
                    "parameters": {
                        "customBulkActions": [],
                        "maxColumnWidth": 300,
                        "minColumnWidth": 40,
                        "mode": "variable",
                        "totals": true
                    },
                    "type": "table",
                    "options": {}
                }
            }
```

How would I be able to use the results of that in another step, via pigql parameter or non-pigql parameters? Especially when needing to reference the derived column names, e.g the group by resulting column names.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I did not get your question completely but will try my best

As you want to use result of your step to be used somewhere else 
I believe you want result value as string to be extracted from step

Hence Syntax will be

> {{cell(.result, , "").asString()}}

Now if you want data of column TotalPrice at first row you syntax will be

> {{cell(Source_Step.result, 0, "TotalPrice").asString()}}